# How to display main menu item after the seleted submenu?

Tags: menu, mobile, ce-1.9.2.2, topmenu

Am working in magento 1.9.2.2. In mobile view, When I click the main menu the submenu items are displayed but the rest of the main menu items are sticking to the same place.I want the rest of the main menu items to be displayed below the opened submenu.

Answer (score 0):

Answer found. In my stylesheet  height of the `.nav-primary` was fixed like this:

`nav-primary li{
 position:relative;
 height:34px;
 }`

when I removed the `height:34px;` the menu item and the submenu item was displayed perfectly.